# Dont load the page until banner image is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I have different images that load into a banner image. I don't want the page to load until the image has loaded.

```
<div id="banner-image" class="col-md-12">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/pAqR6tw.png">
</div>
```

I have looked at several ways of preloading the image with `JQuery`, which all seem incredibly heavy. I wonder if anyone has any ideas for a more lightweight solution?

Comment: Doing it with js, no jquery is a possibility. And is relatively easy. `var img = document.createElement('img'); img.onload = somefunction; img.src = 'foo.jpg';`

Comment: is there a way to do it without having to declare the img src? as  I will have lots of different images.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of the rest of the page content in an element (say, a `div`) with a class that hides it (say, `"hidden"`). Make sure your banner markup is **very** near the top (ideally, immediately after the opening `<body>` tag). Then do this:

```
<div id="banner-image" class="col-md-12">
<img class="img-responsive"
     src="http://i.imgur.com/pAqR6tw.png"
     onload="$('#content').removeClass('hidden');">
</div>
```

Or better yet, for this specific use case, avoid the jQuery dependency:

```
<div id="banner-image" class="col-md-12">
<img class="img-responsive"
     src="http://i.imgur.com/pAqR6tw.png"
     onload="document.getElementByid('content').className = '';">
</div>
```

...so that jQuery doesn't have to be fully loaded when the image's `load` event occurs.

If you prefer not to use `onXyz` attributes, you can give your `img` an `id` and put this code after your `jquery.js` `script` tag (ideally just before the closing `</body>` tag):

```
var $img = $("#the-img-id");
$img.one("load", function() {
    $("#content").removeClass("hidden");
});
if ($img[0].complete) {
    $img[0].trigger("load");
}
```

That handles the potential race condition around the `load` event.

Answer (score -1):

```js
/*$("img").one("load", function() {
  alert('loaded')
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});*/
function onImagesLoaded($container, callback) {
    var $images = $container.find("img");
    var imgCount = $images.length;
    if (!imgCount) {
        callback();
    } else {
        $("img", $container).each(function () {
            $(this).one("load error", function () {
                imgCount--;
                if (imgCount == 0) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
    }
}

onImagesLoaded($("#banner-image"), function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```

```css
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 99;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="banner-image" class="col-md-12">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/pAqR6tw.png">
</div>
```